# How to upgrade stellar account, forgot password

Tags: upgrade

I tried using the recover password feature at launch.stellar.org, but it doesn't work. I enter the username and leave recovery code blank and it returns the error "Unable to contact the server." I'm sure that's the username because I can see it in the welcome email.

Comment: It fails with: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.stellar.org/user/recover' from origin 'https://launch.stellar.org' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: I disabled CORS in the browser and tried again, it just 404s. I guess forgot password is not maintained anymore.